# Fire Notification at 10 AM of morning and at every 24 hours

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager() to fire notification. But don't know how to set to fire at 10 AM of and at every 24 hours. Any one please help me.

**My code is as below:**

```
        Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

For every 24 hours try this code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diffMillis = now - pref.getLong("CurrentTimeMillis", 0);
if( diffMillis >= (3600000  * 24) ) {

 // Your code here:)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putLong("CurrentTimeMillis", System.currentTimeMillis());
editor.commit();

} else {
 // too early
}
```

Comment: @jeetenParmar . . if it helped ,then dont forget to tick or up up vote .

Answer (score 0):

```
 Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```